# CoreData IOS9 Bug?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift2

I am following a great book from AppCoda, it was working on IOS8 but give many errors now:

```
// Load menu items from database
if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MenuItem")
    var e: NSError?
    menuItems = managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &e) as! [MenuItem]
    if e != nil {
        println("Failed to retrieve record: \(e!.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

After Conversion to IOS9:

```
// Load menu items from database
if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MenuItem")
    let e: NSError?
    menuItems = (try! managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)) as! [MenuItem]
    if e != nil {
        print("Failed to retrieve record: \(e!.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

So I change back "let by var" and still get a warning = Variable 'e' was never mutated; consider changing to let constant. I need var in this block, how can I get rid of this warning?
Any help is more than welcome

Comment: Why do you need it to be a `var` if you're never mutating it?

Answer (score 2):

The new `try` means that the `error` isn't used, and indeed your code isn't using it really, you just define it and then check if anything happened with it, which will never be true. You should delete the `error` and use `catch` to handle problem situations.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it is done now:

```
...
do { 
  let items = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
  // do something with items
}
catch { /* react to error */ }
```